# Как поменять блоки местами при каждом четном элементе?

Tags: html, css

На сайте реализована выдача товаров из БД, где есть картинка, имя и описание. Все в одном блоке: картинка с левой стороны, а имя и описание с правой стороны.

```
@foreach (var p in @Model.Gdss)
{
  @Html.Partial("GdsSummary", p)
}
```

Вот *GdsSummary*:

```
<section class="textblock">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class = "pic">
      @if (Model.ImageData != null)
      {
        <img src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "Gds", new { Model.GdsId })" />
      }
    </div>
    <div class="gds">           
      <h2>@Model.Name</h2>
      <p>@Model.Description</p>   
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Хотелось бы сделать следующее: допустим, в базе 7 товаров. Нужно чтобы каждый четный менял положение картинки (`class="pic"`) и описания (`class="gds"`) т.е. чтобы на *2, 4* и *6* товарах картинка и описание менялись местами.

В *CSS* есть селектор `nth-child` возможно ли им реализовать задуманное и как? Возможно ли как-то указать, чтобы он менял именно `<div class = "pic">` и `<div class="gds">` в этом `textblock`? Если так не получится, то как в принципе менять местами картинку и описание на четных элементах?

Заранее очень благодарю за ответ!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавьте css, вроде моего:

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
}

.pic {
  margin-right: 16px;
}

.textblock:nth-child(even) .wrap {
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.textblock:nth-child(even) .wrap .pic {
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 16px;
}
```

```html
<section class="textblock">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="pic">
      <img src="http://beerhold.it/100/100" />
    </div>
    <div class="gds">
      <h2>@Model.Name</h2>
      <p>@Model.Description</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="textblock">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="pic">
      <img src="http://beerhold.it/100/100" />
    </div>
    <div class="gds">
      <h2>@Model.Name</h2>
      <p>@Model.Description</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="textblock">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="pic">
      <img src="http://beerhold.it/100/100" />
    </div>
    <div class="gds">
      <h2>@Model.Name</h2>
      <p>@Model.Description</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="textblock">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="pic">
      <img src="http://beerhold.it/100/100" />
    </div>
    <div class="gds">
      <h2>@Model.Name</h2>
      <p>@Model.Description</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score -1):

CSS не может менять местами элементы html-верстки. CSS может менять отображение этих элементов.

Тут простейший пример четных-нечетных элементов:

```
li {
color: black;
}
li:nth-child(odd) {
color: red;
}
li:nth-child(even) {
color: blue;
}


<ul>
<li>ho</li>
<li>ho</li>
<li>ho</li>
<li>ho</li>
<li>ho</li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/K3TuN/1323/

Comment: Вы не правы, может. Посмотрите пример Andrey Fedorov

Comment: @Crantisz а что, в его ответе как-то меняется расположение хтмл-элементов? по-моему, меняется только их отображение.

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko меняестся с точки зрения верстки. Не меняется с точки зрения DOM

Comment: Если бы это поддерживалось во всех браузерах...
http://caniuse.com/#search=flex-direction 
В IE10 и ранее - не поддерживается, в других старых браузерах тоже не будет работать.
Решить можно просто через nth-child: например, в четном элементе флотить картинку влево, а описание вправо, а в нечетном - наоборот.

Comment: @labris аргумент про недостаточную поддержку браузерами флексбокса уже не принимается. распространение в России ИЕ9 на уровне фаерфокса 25 или хрома 41. ЮСИ браузером пользуются больше, чем ИЕ 9, хотя я уверен, что разработчики его вообще почти не проверяют.